# Using Google Sheets to import the last 5 Days of Daily Open, Close, High and Low Prices from GoogleFinance. "CURRENCY:EURGBP"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope you are well and keeping safe in these times.

This problem I have been facing trying to get Google Sheets to run smoothly has been annoying me for a while now but I can never get this to work. I need help!

On Google Sheets, I am trying to pull the data from =GoogleFinance but I keep getting errors.

I tried this simple code to start getting something but it never works.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURGBP", "OPEN", TODAY(),)
```

Then I need to figure out how to get the last 5 days worth.

How do I get the 5 days of prices for the Daily Open, Close, High & Low so I can run some calculations?

If you can get me the correct formula I will be very thankful.

Happy New Year

Answer (score 0):

> "currency" – The currency in which the security is priced. Currencies don't have trading windows, so open, low, high, and volume won't return for this argument.

so the correct formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURGBP", "all", TODAY()-5, TODAY(), "daily"))
```

[image]

---

but you can do:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURGBP%3DX/history?p=EURGBP", "table", 1), 
 "limit 5", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

I still have this issue with an error that comes up.

"ERROR - The results for GOOGLEFINANCE is not available"

What am I missing?

Comment: those errors can be only hidden by wrapping the whole formula into IFERROR()